# Hibernate: Subclass foreign key columns not null for InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

With SINGLE_TABLE inheritance, the columns representing subclass attributes have to be nullable, even if the attribute itself is mandatory. But in our case, Hibernate generates not null constraints even when it shouldn't. Example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Animal {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String name;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class Pet extends Animal {
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Person owner;

  ...
}

@Entity
public class WildAnimal extends Animal {
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String primaryHabitat;

  ...
}
```

The generated DDL is (target is HSQLDB):

```
create table Animal (DTYPE varchar(31) not null, id integer not null, 
                     name varchar(255) not null, primaryHabitat varchar(255), 
                     owner_id integer not null, primary key (id))
```

As you see, owner_id gets a not null constraint, even if it is not used by WildAnimal. Note also that this is a problem with @ManyToOne, but not @Basic.

Adding a @JoinColumn(nullable = true) has no effect.

I'd guess this is a bug in Hibernate, but my question is whether it is possible to work around this and still enforce the "mandatoryness" of the attribute/association?

We're using Hibernate Core 4.1.8.

**Edit**

Person looks like this (no association with Pet):

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String name;

  ....
}
```

Comment: Is Pet > Person bidirectional? Can you show the Person class?

Comment: It's unidirectional. Person has no knowledge of Pets.

Comment: Can you try explicitly defining the join Column for the manyToOne. @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", nullable = true). The JPA spec says the default for nullable should be true however may be worth a try. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#nullable()

Comment: Specifying column name in JoinColumn does not change anything, and I already tried nullable, as stated in the post.

Comment: Remove the null constraint after schema generated or specify a columnDefiniton attribute (although not ideal as database specific) or, as you say, live without it. One side effect of not having it is that Person will always be eagerly fetched even if you were to specify Lazy.

Comment: I tried to use a columnDefinition, but apparently it was ignored. Anyways, it is database specific, so I guess I'll have to live without it then.